# If the equation $||x+3|-2|=p$,where $p$ is a constant integer,has exactly three distinct solutions,then find the value of $p$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

If the equation $||x+3|-2|=p$,where $p$ is a constant integer,has exactly three distinct solutions,then find the value of $p$.

---

$||x+3|-2|=p$
$|x+3|-2=\pm p$
$|x+3|=2\pm p$
$x+3=2+p,2-p,-2-p,-2+p$
$x=-1+p,-1-p,-5-p,-5+p$
But i dont know how to solve it further.I dont know how to use the information that it has three distinct solutions.
Please help me.Thanks.

Comment: Equate the 2nd and last values of x.

Comment: Basically what we want is $x_1=x_2\neq x_3\neq x_4$

Comment: Why only the second and the last value of $x$ to be equated,not others,any reasoning behind it?@AdityaAgarwal

Comment: Or can we equate any two?

Comment: See the answer below, this is because we strictly want $x_1=x_2\neq x_3\neq x_4$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you have come up with 4 solutions. Since the problem says there are only 3 distinct solutions, two of the solutions must be equal to each other. There are two possibilities
$$
-1+p=-5-p \implies p=-2 \implies x = -3,+1,-7
$$
or
$$
-1-p=-5+p \implies p = 2 \implies x = +1,-3,-7
$$